# Why isn't Windows Update completing an installation?

Tags: windows-7

I've got Windows 7 Ultimate.  For the last 3 days or so, it has tried, repeatedly, to install some updates.  Each and every time I shut it down, it tries.  What's wrong?  Why doesn't it install whatever the heck it's trying to install?

Comment: can you be more specific? which updates? do you get an error message? if so, what does it say?

Comment: OK, I've just looked at my system logs and found 3 updates not installing properly. Here they are:

Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x800705b4: Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2158563).

Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x800705b4: Update for Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility View List for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2362765).

Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x800705b4: Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB979538).

Answer (score 1):

Check the application and system logs in the event viewer.  I know there were updates to most all versions of the .NET framework this week, so especially if you have multiple versions of .NET installed it could take a while to get through them all.  We had several computers take a few days to get through everything successfully.  'Install Updates and Shut Down' would succeed for one update but fail for others and take a looooooong time trying.  As I said, they finally completed but you can probably tell what's going on more clearly from the events.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just checked my application log and found several errors related to the attempted upgrade. Here's some from the first one:

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Windows Error Reporting
Date:          10/2/2010 6:39:42 AM
Event ID:      1001
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      TARDIS
Description:
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CbsPackageServicingFailure2
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in order to stop this irritating behavior.  I went to the system log in event viewer and found the updates it was trying to install, that failed to install.  I then went to Windows Update, found the relevant updates and installed them, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Windows Update Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/512a5183-ffab-40c5-8a68-021e32467565/windows-update-troubleshooter) from Microsoft. It will fix your update database.